# can't find prev element after getting all elements with same class (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to JQuery. I made a image gallery with a grid layout and added a modal view with prev & next buttons with simple javascript. Worked fine. Now I'm trying to use jquery api's to do the same things (open, close, next, prev). Open, close events work fine. I'm stuck on prev/next events. I'm getting undefined values for `imgIndex` after using .prev(). Surely because i'm wrong with the tree navigation. Can't find a way out...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentImg;

    $(".myImg").click(function(){   //open the selected image
        currentImg = $(this);
        $("#myModal").css("display", "block");
        img_index = $(this).attr("imgIndex");
        showModalImg($(this).attr("src"));
    });
    $(".prev").click(function(){
        alert (currentImg.prev().attr("imgIndex"));  //undefined
        if(currentImg.attr("imgIndex") == 1){
            alert("first");
            currentImg = $(".myImg").last();    //ok
        }
        else{
            alert("not first");
            currentImg = currentImg.prev();
        }
        alert(currentImg.attr("imgIndex"));  //undefined
    });
```

This is the structure of the gallery..

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="" class="myImg" imgIndex="1"></img>
                    <img src="" class="myImg" imgIndex="2"></img>
                    <img src="" class="myImg" imgIndex="3"></img>
                    <img src="" class="myImg" imgIndex="4"></img>
                    <img src="" class="myImg" imgIndex="5"></img>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="" class="myImg" imgIndex="6"></img>
                    <img src="" class="myImg" imgIndex="7"></img>
                    <img src="" class="myImg" imgIndex="8"></img>
                    <img src="" class="myImg" imgIndex="9"></img>
                    <img src="" class="myImg" imgIndex="10"></img>
                </div>
                so on...
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <img class="modal-content" id="img01" width="100%">
                    <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
                    <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using XHTML ? If not, in HTML, the <img> tag has no end tag.

Comment: initially the tag wasn't closed. Nothing different

Comment: When is "initially"? Anyway, I am talking about now, today.

Comment: I closed the tags afterwards as an atempt to solve the problem. Didn't help

Comment: My comment wasn't about solving your problem, it was about correcting your code!… https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple reasons why it would come up undefined:

1. Right now currentImg only ever gets set if you actually click an image. So if you never clicked an image, it will be remain undefined.
2. Because of the DOM structure where images 6-10 are in a different column, prev() will always be undefined for imgIndex=6 because there is no previous element in this case. If you need the layout to be this way, then you could cache the images upfront, how about something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentImg;
    var img_index = 1;
    var $images = $(".myImg");

    $(".myImg").click(function(){   //open the selected image
        currentImg = $(this);
        console.log(currentImg.attr('imgIndex'));
        $("#myModal").css("display", "block");
        img_index = $(this).attr("imgIndex");
        console.log("new img_index:" + img_index)
        //showModalImg($(this).attr("src"));
    });

    $(".prev").click(function(){
        
        console.log("current index:" + (img_index - 1));
       
        if(img_index == 1){
            alert("first");
            currentImg = $images.eq($images.length - 1);
        }
        else{
            alert("not first");
            currentImg = $images.eq(img_index - 2);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The right reason was the 2nd. It was so simple to fix -facepalm-